# Enlist each element of anonymous Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I received an object **fi**.. and it is a field of someone anonymous object.

I want to enlist each element of the object **fi** if it belongs to Generic class List

```
if(fi.FieldType.IsGenericType && fi.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
   {
      foreach (object element in (XXX) k.Value)
      {

      }
   }
```

Well with that particular object I know it is List, so I can cast (List).

My question is: what should I cast to, to do not care about what Type of the list element?

I tried List<>, List .. it says I have to set the element Type to get cast succeeded.

Help.. pls.

Array is just for to make it runnable

[image]

UPD: I think cast to an Interface (IList) is available only if you have deal with Object, in my case it is an object's value.. so it means that if I have a deal with Generic, then I should continue work with the Object, but not with its value, right?

Comment: You can use `is` keyword. [MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is).

Comment: If you just want to iterate over the elements as objects cast it to IEnumerable.

Comment: I think cast to an Interface is available only if you have deal with Object

Comment: in my case it is an object's value.. so it means that if I have a deal with Generic, then I should continue work with Object but not it's value, right?

Comment: The only object you can do a foreach for is IEnumerable so try to cast it to that. It is inherited by all lists collections arrays and so on. You should be able to cast anything to that. but my guess is your fi FieldType is not the same as k.Value

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the field value for a particular instance, then you can iterate over it. You can achieve this as follows:

```
if (fi.FieldType.IsGenericType && fi.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    var value = (IList)fi.GetValue(myObject); // <- get field value, cast it to IList
    foreach (var element in value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't want to cast. I tried List<> List<T> IList

Comment: k.Value is exactly like your's fi.GetValue(myObject)

Comment: @VitaliPetrov Then your code is missing some information... What is k and where does it come from? What do you mean by "it doesn't want to cast"? Casting to IList is safe in this case. I tried my code and it does just what I expect it to do.

Comment: pls, see the pic i have added

Comment: I still do not see what k is and why casting to IList won't work for you.

Comment: else if (fi.IsStatic) k.Value = fi.GetValue(null);
                    else if (!fi.IsStatic) k.Value = fi.GetValue(parent);

Comment: k is just a class with the field Value

Comment: the object itself is in fi

Comment: All I can do is to ask you once again to provide a more detailed sample showing what k is, where you get your FieldInfos from and what you want to do with them. If I got your question right, my answer should help you. Since it apparently does not help you, you will need to work on the question if you expect help from me.

Comment: i don't think you can help me )) sorry mate i've wrote all clear.. thanks anyway